# Simulate Hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Given the existing "buttons"

HTML:

```
 <div id="MB">
    <ul class="list">
       <li id="post-5"><a href="#post-5">5</a></li>
       <li id="post-4"><a href="#post-4">4</a></li>
       <li id="post-3"><a href="#post-3">3</a></li>
       <li id="post-2"><a href="#post-2">2</a></li>
       <li id="post-1"><a href="#post-1">1</a></li>
    </ul> 
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #MB .list li a {
        float:left;
        color:#333;
        background:#f6f6f6;
        border:1px solid #eaeaea;
        border-right:none;
        padding:0 8px;
        }

   #MB .list li a:hover,
   #MB .list li a:focus {
        color:#fff;
        border:1px solid #333333;
        border-right:none;
        background:#404040;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
```

I'd like to simulate "hover" automatically on each button, sequentially, every n seconds.

This means that every n seconds a button is "hovered" (changing color etc), at next interval is "turned off" and the following button will "turn on" and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#MB .list a:hover,
#MB .list a:focus,
#MB .list .active a {
  /* hover styles */
}
```

(I've simplified your selectors a bit, I would also suggest trying to remove the outer `div` as these are often unnecessary and the `ul` alone is enough)

Javascript hover:

```
function setHover() {
    if ($('#MB .list .active').next().length) {
        $('#MB .list .active').next().addClass('active').end().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#MB .list .active').removeClass('active');
        $('#MB .list li:first-child').addClass('active');
    }
}

setInterval(setHover, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm following your solution. It is what I was looking for. Running Firebug, I can see the class "active" being assigned to each "li" element, looping through list items correctly upon interval; however the style doesn't visually change, I believe because of the inner "a" element.

Comment: Did you update your CSS selector? that will apply the hover style to any `a` that is a child of `.active` class.

Comment: Yes, it will apply to *ALL* the "a" element child of the "active" class at the same time...

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and [`jQuery.trigger('mouseover', …)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

Define a third selector like

> #MB .list li a:hover,#MB .list li
>   a:focus,#MB .list li a.simFocus  {
>       …
>       }

and then add and remove the "simFocus" class time-based per javascript code.

Comment: Almost - but optimize a little: use only .simFocus. Doesn't change function, but simplifying selectors by using more names instead of hierarchies is a very good speed optimization. So instead of
  #elem ul li a.myclass
one could use 
  .elem-list-link
which is used only in that context, i.e. in links(a) below li below ul below id="elem".

Answer (score -1):

Try adding onClick="return true" in your link a href tag

```
<a href="../about.php" onMouseOver="mopen('m2')" onMouseOut="mclosetime()" onClick="return true">About us</a>
```

the onClick="return true" should simulate a cursor hovering over then leaving the hover area. effectivly giving you a hover effect.

keep in mind, ur finger has to touch the button for the hover effect to take place, which means the user will only see the change for a second or two before the link loads a page.