# Simulate Hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, konacha

Currently, I have some jQuery/Javascript code that toggles the css class 'ui-state-hovered' when a user hovers the mouse over certain elements, and I want to write a test in konacha to test this piece of code.

How would I write this function in Javascript with the help of jQuery?

Return true if when a user hovers over an element $('.someClass li:first'), the class 'ui-state-hovered' exists.
Else return false.

How would I simulate a user hovering their mouse over that element?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169449/simulate-hover-using-jquery

Comment: Another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983169/hover-item-with-jquery

Comment: I'm not sure it's duplicate, the OP asked how to trigger a hover event, not how to create the event listener for hover

Answer (score 29):

Try `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$('.someClass li:first').mouseenter().mouseleave();
```

From jQuery docs

> Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for: `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/wh5N9/

Try below to check for an class that would have added in hover

```
$("#test").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log('Has class hover ' + $(this).hasClass('ui-state-hovered'));
}).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log('Has class hover ' + $(this).hasClass('ui-state-hovered'));
})
```

**Make sure the above is registered after `.hover`**

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/wh5N9/2/

Answer (score 7):

Shorthand set mouseenter/mouseleave events

```
$(".someClass li:first").hover(
  // Mouse Over
  function(){
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hovered");
  },
  // Mouse Out
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hovered");
});
```

**EDIT**

Set event mouseenter

```
$(".someClass li:first").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hovered");
  }
```

Set event mouseleave

```
$(".someClass li:first").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hovered");
});
```

To simulate mouseover:

```
$(".someClass li:first").trigger("mouseenter");
```

To simulate mouseout:

```
$(".someClass li:first").trigger("mouseleave");
```

To check for a class:

```
$(".someClass li:first").hasClass("ui-state-hovered");
```

To return true if has a class:

```
function checkClass(elem, class){
  return $(elem).hasClass(class);
};
```

**EDIT 2**

I've never use Konacha before, but if I were to take a stab at it using [this guide at solitr.com as my guide](http://www.solitr.com/blog/2012/04/konacha-tutorial-javascript-testing-with-rails/), I'd say:

HTML

```
<div id="testDiv" class="foo">Some Text</div>
```

jQuery

```
checkClass = function(elem, class){
    return $(elem).hasClass(class);
};
```

Konacha

```
describe('checkClass', function() {
    it('should be true if elem has class', function() {
        checkClass("#testDiv", "foo").should.be.true;
        checkClass("#testDiv", "bar").should.be.false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

```
$('someClass li:first').mouseover();
```

This should trigger the event

Comment: If he has used `$.fn.hover` then the correct method is `.mouseenter()`

Comment: @Esailija - Good point but I checked and it seems that `mouseover` triggers also `mouseenter` (and vice versa) see here: http://jsfiddle.net/F4S2K/2/

Answer (score 0):

using the console you could try $('#yourelement').trigger('mouseover');

Answer (score -3):

Write function on hover

```
$('.someClass li:first').hover(function(){
      return $(this).attr('class').indexOf('ui-state-hovered') > -1;
});
```

Comment: u r adding a listener to events, not triggering them