# Force element state hover in function of another hovered element / jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I saw many things about the state hover and jQuery but nothing about my issue. 
I want to force a class to become :hover when another class is `:hover`. 
Difficult to explain so here my code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {    
if($('.h').is(':hover')){ 
    $('.h .btn-1e').trigger('mousover');
}
});
```

The fact is that second class hover is a bit complicated and I can't make it by `addClass` / `removeClass` (the hover include `:after` things, animations etc ..)

Thanks for the help and sorry about my english!

Comment: Have you tried .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038638/simulate-hover-in-jquery ?

Comment: I saw the post but i don't think this what i need. I don't want to add a class when one element is hovered, i just want to simulate the hover on the second element when the first is hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in that way:

Define your own new hover class (i know you wrote, that you hover css is complicated but of course you can replace your hover with a hover class, here you can also add :after ...):

```
.class1,
.class2 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: gray;
}
/* your element has an additional hover class */
.class1.hover,
.class2.hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now set this hover class in this hover event function with jquery:

```
$(".class1, .class2").hover(function() {
    //mouseenter
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function(){
    //mouseleave
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

And now you can say, that all `class2` elements should become the hover state (that is your hover class) when the mouse hovers a `class1` element:

```
$(".class1").mouseenter(function() {
    //on hover class1 force hover state to class2
    $(".class2").mouseenter();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    //remove it on mouseleave
    $(".class2").mouseleave();
});
```

I've made you a jsfiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/0txLn21c/1/

For more information you can read the API:

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

I hope, this could help you and i don't know your code, but i think it isn't impossible to use a hover class in your case. For example you can give your hover class an `:after` element or an animation to:

```
.class1.hover:after {
    /* content, animations ... */
}
```

Comment: thank you @sim ! But after some tries it's still not working.. I got this error : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I made a jsfiddle too here : https://jsfiddle.net/zcgrfc9v/6/

Comment: i cant't reproduce your error, but is it right, that you want to animate the buttons when mouseenter in the .choice divs? So i made this only with CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/zcgrfc9v/7/ if you don't want to do this, let me know!

Comment: Well, it's perfect like this ! Thank you so much Sim ! You saved my life

Answer (score 0):

I usually trigger events like this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {    
    if($('.h').is(':hover')){ 
        $('.h .btn-1e').mouseover();
    }
});
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: @Jordan Have you checked that `$('.h .btn-1e').length` is not 0? If it is, it means your selector isn't finding anything.

Comment: Yes it returns me "1" for $('.h .btn-1e').length