# Is there any alternate way to do mouse hover in selenium box using java 1.8 gecko driver 0.19 and firefox 56

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Using Actions is giving exception as ***unsupportedCommandException.***

Tried to do something like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Actions")).click();
```

`Element` is the `webElement` which I tried to hover.

Tried this also:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].focus();",element);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

But no luck.

I am working with **seleniumbox** and using latest version of **selenium 3.9.1**.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question only to **Mouse Hover** an element first you have to wait for the element to be *visible*. With *Selenium-Java Client v3.9.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.35* and *Chrome v 63.0* this block of code works perfect at my end :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_element")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

---

### Update

As per your question :

- You are using *GeckoDriver v0.19* and *Firefox 56.x*

As per the trace logs :

- You are using *Selenium Client v3.4.0*

[image: 3.4.0]

The Release Notes of [*Geckodriver v0.19.0 (2017-09-16)*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) clearly mentions :

```
Note that with geckodriver 0.19.0 the following versions are recommended: - Firefox 55.0 (and greater) - Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
```

Hence you see the error :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown
```

Comment: Action is not working. On Using actions, it gives unsupportedcommandexception. I have already provided wait using Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: My main aim is to hover over an element and then click on an element which comes in drop down . Drop down is visible on mouse hover and disappers after element loses focus.  <div class="Menu">
              <ul type="none">
                <li> <a href="F">All </a> </li>       I want to select "All" in this.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, I didnt change my question, i just tried to elaborate more. I have already tried your code and it is not working.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo
      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' This is the exception. Code works on local but not on remote.

Comment: But I am using 3.9.1 version only. My pom.xml contents are :                               <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.seleniumquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>seleniumquery</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.9.1</version>
      </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
     <version>3.9.1</version>
     </dependency>

Comment: Updated my Answer with all the help I can afford from my side. Good luck.

Comment: @user892077 Are you using eclipse? Try to `right-click` on your project. Then select `Maven -> Update Project`. Also, make sure you removed any libraries you added manually which might override libraries downloaded by maven dependencies.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Yes I am using eclipse. Version is neon . and I have updated maven project also but it is giving exception.

Comment: @user892077 Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue while running on sauce labs. In my local I don't see a problem because I am using 3.7.1 but Sauce uses 3.4.0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `Action` doesn't work. The possible solution is to change the version of **Firefox** and **GeckoDriver** to lower (Stable version).

**Example for IEDriver:**

```
selenium-standalone install --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1

selenium-standalone start --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1
```

Comment: Any other solution ? Actually I tried changing version also, but as I am using seleniumbox , downgraded version is having many problems such as opening a new tab and sendkeys, that is why I have upgraded the version. Is there any alternate way of doing this

Comment: Try to use click and hold insted of hover. It's not the same but if you need the state of your element and take screenshot that it could be a good solution. Did you try to use mouseDown ?

Comment: Try to use this JavaScript solution from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover) or this [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038638/simulate-hover-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try if changing the code like this helps:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement( driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Actions"))).click().build().perform();
```