# firing css :hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a css rule applied on a tag like this

```
a { background-color: #000; }
a:hover {background-color: #ff0000; }
```

I want to fire its hover behavior using jquery, is it possible? this code is running fine but not change the bg color to red.

```
$('.me a').mouseenter();
```

Why I need this?
I have to write automated tests for my web application's menu and thats I need it.

The point here is CAN I execute browser behavior attached to a:hover using jquery?

Comment: Why you want to do something yourself which is already provided by default

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I think we can assume that the effect is to be simulated *without* an actual mouse hover.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate Hover using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169449/simulate-hover-using-jquery)

Comment: @DavidHedlund Nasty thoughts ..

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yes I need to write automated tests

Comment: First, demonstrate your failure; your CSS should be enough, barring specificity issues. What's your html and your relevant CSS to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DavidThomas: The question is perfectly specific. OP says "I want to fire its hover behavior using jquery". But by all means, [here's the reproduced problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5t2MP/). Note that I just pieced that together, it is not the specific use case that OP has in mind.

Comment: Ops to much answeres but not body is getting my point here.... I know I can handle it using class names and editing css etc. I have no access to web applications code.

Comment: Have you tried anything as simple as $('.me a').trigger("mouseover") ?

Comment: @Alex Yes I have tried that too...

Comment: Now I'm lost, you want to handle it using CSS since you have no access to application code, yet you want a jQuery answer?

Comment: @RickCalder: OP mentions in comments that they are writing automated tests, so the requirement makes sense. Just as you an I cannot alter the stack overflow source code, but we may still fire ad hoc javascript at it.

Comment: @coure2011 Yeah, my bad. That only works to trigger script-behaviour and not CSS.

Comment: @coure2011: If you can't change the CSS source, perhaps you can alter the stylesheets at runtime. I've posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you cannot set the `hover` state programmatically.

As others have pointed out, you can set a class programmatically, and use the same style for the element when hovered or classed:

```
a.hover, a:hover { ... }
```

You could do something similar with `:focus`, which is also programmatically settable ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mky3a/)).

However, it appears that you have access only to fire javascript at the application, and not to change any parts of its source. What you would have to do, in this scenario, is to change the css rule itself using java script.

In the setup of your tests, you may change all `:hover` styles to styles that additionally accept a class name:

```
function allowMockHover() {

    // iterate over all styleSheets
    for(var i = 0, l = document.styleSheets.length; i < l; i++) {
        var s = document.styleSheets[i];
        if(s.cssRules == null) continue;

        // iterate over all rules in styleSheet
        for(var x = 0, rl = s.cssRules.length; x < rl; x++) {
            var r = s.cssRules[x];
            if(r.selectorText && r.selectorText.indexOf(':hover') >= 0) {
               fixRule(r);
            }
        }
    }

}

function fixRule(rule) {

    // if the current rule has several selectors, treat them separately:
    var parts = rule.selectorText.split(',');
    for(var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(parts[i].indexOf(':hover') >= 0) {
           // update selector to be same + selector with class
           parts[i] = [ parts[i], parts[i].replace(/:hover/gi, '.mock-hover') ].join(',');
        }
    }

    // update rule
    rule.selectorText = parts.join(',');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxyab/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="#">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").mouseover(function(){
    $("a").css("background-color","yellow");
  });
  $("a").mouseout(function(){
    $("a").css("background-color","lightgray");
  });
});
```

Jsfiddle examplw http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1110/

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS rule so that the styles also have a class name:

```
a:hover,
a.mouseenter
{
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Then you can simply add/remove the class whenever you wish to give the hover effect:

```
$('.me a').addClass("mouseenter");
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/X3Hm9/*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.me a').hover(function (){ $(this).css("background-color,"red")}, 
function(){$(this).css("background-color,"black")});
```

should help you :)

Here you can learn more about hover() in Jquery http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: he already has a hover class in CSS. I think he just wants to reuse the style for some javascript event.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, here's not really anyway to trigger the browsers default hover behaviour (that is what you want isn't it?). But even if there was, as you're doing it ( `$('a').mouseenter();` ) then you'd just simulate like a fraction of a second of a hover, as just right after it would default to it's normal behaviour. A simpler way to do it might simply be to add a class, like so:

```
$('a').addClass('is-hover');
```

with the following css:

```
a:hover,
a.is-hover {
    background: red;
}
```

There's really no need for a fiddle, but here it is anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/5fqXs/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reuse the CSS rule, do following

1) change the CSS rule to

```
a:hover, .hovered {background-color: #ff0000; }
```

2) add this javascript code

```
$('.me a').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
},function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it that I've used is:

start simulating hover:
`$('.me a').trigger("mouseover")`

end simulating hover:
`$('.me a').trigger("mouseleave)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.me a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'red')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Reasoning behind this code compared to manipulating the CSS directly is CSS belongs in the stylesheet NOT in the individual pages. Now imagine you want to change the background colour application wide and you're changing the CSS in the jQuery directly, have fun. With the example below you change the .hoverClass in your CSS sheet and you're done.

```
a { background-color: #000; }
.hoverClass {background-color: #ff0000; }



$('.me a').mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('hoverClass');
}).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('hoverClass');
});
```

Although as mentioned this seems utterly pointless since the concept of a hover class is what you are trying to achieve.

```
.me>a:hover {background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: forget the jQuery entirely is a bit of a bold remark unless you are intimately familiar with the scenarios during which OP may want to simulate the hover effect.

Comment: Of course sometimes the situation might require it, for the life of me I can't think of a situation where a hover on an a element would to be honest, you'll notice I did supply the requested jQuery code as well as my personal opinion though ;)

Comment: javascript is redundant only in the particular scenario that you've selected for your example. If all OP wants is to show that effect at mouseenter/mouseleave, then yes, the CSS will be enough (save for some very old versions of IE which I think might not support the pseudo-class). Based on the question alone, it is entirely conceivable that OP wants to use the styles from `:hover` whenever *something else* happens, such as at the click of *another* link.

Comment: Which is exactly WHY I answered his question as asked AS WELL. I fail to see the issue here. While I can't read the OP's mind I do feel it's our responsibility to point out other options at the same time as answering the original question. When I wrote my answer the OP had not yet edited the question to point out why he needed this.

Comment: My issue was that you were calling the script approach superfluous when it is only the case in the specific scenario that you've modeled. It was only a comment, though, and I never intended it to be more than that. The downvote isn't mine, I might add.

Comment: I edited that part out, you're correct there. Honestly anonymous downvotes shouldn't be allowed in my opinion. Mine is the only answer that actually handles the question in a way that overrides the original hover behaviour permanently and allows for application wide updating easily =/